How do I make the video (as a background) resizable depending on the screen resolution?
Here is the html code:
<div class="wrapper">
     <video autoplay muted loop>
          <source src="resources/promo-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
</div>

Here is the css code:
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: -100;
    margin: 2.5em;
}
.wrapper video {
    min-width: 1600px;
    max-height: 800px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -100;
    display: block;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 20%;
}

Here is what it looks like right now. The output I wanted is the one on top but it doesn't have the same output on the other window.

Try this one. Basically, I stretch the video to all sides using position absolute, and added min-width and min-height to be 100%.
Check on full page it will stretch:


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>



